# Mongoose custom query helpers in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I am using Mongoose's [query helpers](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#query-helpers) to add some functionality to my schemas, for example, to exclude soft-deleted items:

```
schema.query.excludeDeleted = function() {
    return this.where({
        isDeleted: false
    })
};
```

I can type this function (sort of) OK, although `query` isn't in the @types package:

```
(schema as any).query.excludeDeleted = function(this: Query<MyDocument>) {
    return this.where({
        isDeleted: false
    })
};
```

The issue I have is when I come to use these functions, e.g.

```
const documents = await MyDocument.find({}).excludeDeleted();
```

will fail TS compilation as excludeDeleted doesn't exist on `DocumentQuery` (returned by find()).  The obvious hacky solution is:

```
const documents = await (MyDocument.find({}) as any).excludeDeleted();
```

but this means I lose all typing information, as well as making the functions more of a pain to use.

I have been able to find ways of typing a model's static functions, but not query helpers, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have been experiencing this issue as well and found the work around (same as you have done really) to be annoying to use.

If you aren't too bothered if it gets applied to every find / findOne query you could add a query hook which runs right before the query is executed. In the hook it would simply add the filtering onto the query for checking for soft-deleted documents. Once the hook is finished it would be executed.

In my scenario I needed to filter for soft-deleted documents every time I retrieve from the DB so it makes sense to use the hook rather than a query helper. Depends on your situation however.

```js
schema.pre("find", function(this: Query) {
  return this.where("isDeleted").equals(false);
});
schema.pre("findOne", function(this: Query) {
  return this.where("isDeleted").equals(false);
});
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Comment: I'm doing something similar.  I simplified a bit for the question, but we are using pre-hooks to exclude deleted docs on every query, in conjunction with a `withDeleted` query helper to include them when necessary by removing the hook.  Having done some more searching since asking the question I don't think getting proper typing is currently possible without rewriting a chunky part of the `@types/mongoose` definitions.